# Alarm clock doesnot work for the schedule time and day

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am working on alarm clock for my project in android and i am new to programming. I have got my alarm clock app working but it does not work for the schedule time so if I set the clock for Sunday 12 pm it does not work.

```
 public class AlarmClock extends Activity {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private EditText descriptionText;
    private static MainActivity inst;
    private CheckBox checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6,checkBox7;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_clock);
        alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        checkBox1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sundayCheckBox);
        checkBox2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mondayCheckBox);
        checkBox3= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tuesdayCheckBox);
        checkBox4= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wednesdayCheckBox);
        checkBox5= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.thursdayCheckBox);
        checkBox6= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fridayCheckBox);
        checkBox7= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saturdayCheckBox);




    }
    public void save (View v){
        if (checkBox1.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(1);
        }

        if (checkBox2.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(2);
        }

        if (checkBox3.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(3);
        }

        if (checkBox4.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(4);
        }

        if (checkBox5.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(5);
        }

        if (checkBox6.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(6);
        }

        if (checkBox7.isChecked())
        {
            activityToPerform(7);
        }



    }
    private void activityToPerform(int week)
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        descriptionText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcast.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: it is WakefulBroadcastReceiver I am editing my question and putting AlarmBroadcast

Comment: That'll work. You need to fix your manifest. `AlarmBroadcast` is the `<receiver>`. `AlarmNotification` is the `<service>`. And move both outside of the `<activity>` tags, but inside the `<application>` tags.

Comment: thank you for your help....it worked!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Starting API 19, the `alarmManager.set()` method is not delivered at precise time. See this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

You should use `setExact()` instead